# Is the 3DS version of "Link's Awakening" identical to the original?

Tags: version-differences, zelda-links-awakening

I've heard numerous interviews with Miyamoto stating that he'd love to see Link to the Past on the 3DS with 3D. As well it's my understanding that a few games on the 3DS Virtual Console (Excitebike?) have 3D added into them.

Are there any differences between the 3DS version of "Link's Awakening" and the original or DX version? I'm particularly curious if there is 3D in the 3DS version of Link's Awakening.

Comment: Why the VTC and down votes? This is a valid and on-topic question.

Comment: Because the first paragraph and the second paragraph are talking about separate games?

Comment: I believe the Excitebike game I was talking about falls into their "3D Classics" series. It looks like there's a Kirby game, Xevious and Kid Icarus. There's probably more that I don't know of

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a port of the DX version. It is not 3D whatsoever. It does include the Color Dungeon found in the DX version, and is in colour.

Comment: One little addition to your stellar answer would be that if you hold START while selecting the game from the 3ds menu you can play on an awesome 3D purple gameboy color. Which adds a little "newness" to playing this on the 3ds but really doesn't change any gameplay elements. :]

Comment: @stay I am really not sure what you mean here - do you mean the GameBoy image that shows on the upper screen of the selection menu will be a purple GBC? Mine started out that way...

Comment: Actually if you hold down the start button while selecting the game from your 3DS menu it will make your top screen have an awesome purple gameboy color "frame". Which if you turn your 3D on it will look basically like a real gameboy color.. same goes for the original gameboy games and the new gamegear games. :]

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is no. There's no 3D* and the game has no major changes.

However, there are a few minor tweaks to non-gameplay elements:

- Grandma Ulrira no longer has her "YAHOO!" shout; it's been replaced with "HELLO!" and "YIPPEE!".
- Effects that make the screen flash (e.g., capacity upgrades) have been slowed down greatly, like most other Virtual Console games.
- Mamu's song loses the spotlights, which were done by rapidly flashing parts of the screen
- The photobook no longer allows you to print pictures. The game ignores the A button entirely, so you can't even get the "Error 02" message.
- Inaccurate emulation bugs sometimes lead to minor music and graphical inconsistencies

The actual changes to the game itself have been verified by examining the game's content. The ROM itself is a standard *Link's Awakening* ROM with an included text-based patch (applied in real-time).

<sub>* Holding Start or Select when starting the game will render the game at original size (no filtering) with a faux-Game Boy Color border around it. The game screen is slightly sunk into the border using 3D effects.</sub>